# Finding the first item amongst a series of items in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in MySQL DB and I need to find the occurrence of the first BUY / SELL (See Status Column) along with the corresponding **Stock** and its corresponding **Price**

For example I have the following data in my table:

[image]

I have highlighted the occurrence of the first BUY and SELL in yellow for AAPL and in orange for MSFT for a better understanding.

The query in MySQL should give me the following result:

[image]

Comment: the value in SQL table are not ordered  by itself   so what do you want use for get the "first"   .. have you timestamp ?.. autoincrement id ?

Comment: scaisEdge, I have a timestamp in : yyyy-mm-dd format. You may take the date into picture. I thought the date wans't important, hence didn't add it in the above example.

Comment: so  you want the row related  to the older  timestamp_column?

Comment: @scaisEdge: I have added a date column for your reference. Please see edited post. You may order the dates by ASC or DESC and then find the first occurrences of Buy / Sell

Comment: also with the date  your "first"  is not clear  why   8/21/2017, 182.46, BUY  in your  .. result  .. as i comment above the sql data are not order by itself and there is not a implicit sequence in data .,so what are the criteri for get the first (  not only looking to table with eyes)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
SELECT     current.Date, 
           current.Stock, 
           current.Price, 
           current.Status 
FROM       <your table> current 
LEFT JOIN <your table> previous 
ON         previous.Date = 
           (SELECT MAX(t.Date) 
           FROM   <your table> t 
           WHERE  t.Date < current.Date)
WHERE  current.Status <> previous.Status OR previous.Status IS NULL
ORDER BY current.Date
```